# How to draw circle on JavaFX chart

Tags: java, javafx

I develop a JavaFX application and I am struggling with solving this problem:

I have an array of points (x, y) that I am plotting over a scatter chart, you can see in the picture below they appear as a small gray points.

Those points I'd like to enclose with the smallest circle, so for that I have a function called minimalCircle that receives an array of points and while using the [Welzl's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) it returns the minimal enclosing circle (radius + center point)

```
Circle c = minimalCircle(points);
```

The problem occurs when I am trying to plot the circle I retrieve from the function, I make a series containing 1 point which is the center of the circle, and applying a circle shape with the radius of the circle

```
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> minimalCircleSeries(Point[] points) {

          XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
          Circle c = minimalCircle(points);
          javafx.scene.shape.Circle pointCircle = new javafx.scene.shape.Circle(c.center.x, c.center.y, c.r);
          XYChart.Data data = new XYChart.Data(c.center.x, c.center.y);
          data.setNode(pointCircle);
          series.getData().add(data);
          return series;
}
```

Unfortunately when it draws the circle it refers the radius size by pixels while its actually suppose to be real units on the graph, and that cause the circle in the picture below to not be the smallest enclosing circle.

I am trying to find a way to convert the radius scale so the circle will be plotted correctly or to find another way to plot a circle over a scatter chart

Thank you very much for your help !

[Example image of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swmsm.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: btw: axis has coordinate transformation api

Comment: Hi I am trying to simplify my example
So I've got a Circle that it's center point is (0,0) and radius 3

and I'd want to draw it but it draws as 3 pixels radius when I need the circle to be with radius unit of 3 so the axis points will be:
(0,3),(0,-3),(3,0),(-3,0)

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly .. *sigh

Comment: As @kleopatra mentioned, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing a reproducible example will help others to directly focus on your issue without any guessing work. Also it helps to drag more attention, to get your question answered quickly.